# Populate a table on a selective replication slave

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6

We have a setup with a data mining slave with a lot of `replicate-ignore-table=` for tables that aren't needed. Now the developers have requested to populate a table that is currently ignored. How do I go about populating it so that the replication can be started again at the correct point.

I want to avoid locking the table on the master instance as that would lead to application downtime.

We are not yet using GTID.

I have access to MySQL Enterprise Backup if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do these two steps while nothing is being added to the table:

- Manually copy the table to the Slave(s) (even if empty -- need table definition).
- Remove the `replacate-ignore` setting.

Comment: Probably should have added that the "while nothing is being added to the table" is not a viable option as that would lead to application downtime.

Comment: @antonagestam - See if Percona's XtraBackup can pull a stunt.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the replicate-ignore **TABLE NAME** tag from the my.cnf and restart the service the table will populate on the slave automatically ,This should work.